# How to animate vertical lines growing up and down using CSS?

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I want to create a rectangle and animate the drawing of lines. The lines should grow vertically up and down from the rectangle. Totally, I want to have 2 lines growing up, and 2 lines growing down.

This is my current script:

```css
.content {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: #dd8341;
  top: 40%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20%;
  padding: 20px;
}

.vertline {
  width: 2px;
  margin-left: 10%;
  background-color: #dd8341;
  top: 40%;
  animation:lineup 3s forwards;
  position: relative;
}

@keyframes lineup {
  0% {
    height: 0px;
  }
  100% {
    height: 200px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="content"></div>
<div class="vertline"></div>
```

I cannot align all elements correctly. What is the correct way to do this simple task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it without additional *elements*, using the `:before` and `:after` *pseudo-elements* to grow up and down, and `background: linear-gradient()` to create two lines:

```css
.content {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: #dd8341;
  top: 40%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20%;
  padding: 20px;
}

.content:before,
.content:after {
  content: "";
  width: 6px; /* color white ("no color") color (each 2px wide); here you can adjust the width */
  height: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #dd8341, #dd8341 33.33%, #fff 33.33%, #fff 66.66%, #dd8341 66.66%); /* here you can adjust the spacing */
  margin-left: 10%;
  position: absolute; /* needs to be absolute */
  top: 0;
  animation: lineup 3s forwards;
}

.content:after {
  top: 100%;
  animation: linedown 3s forwards;
}

@keyframes lineup {100% {top: -200px; height: 200px}}
@keyframes linedown {100% {height: 200px}}
```

```html
<div class="content"></div>
```

Addition:

```css
/* recommended */
* {box-sizing: border-box}
body {margin: 0}

.content {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: #dd8341;
  top: 40%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20%;
  padding: 20px;
}

.content:before,
.content:after,
.linedown1,
.linedown2 {
  content: "";
  width: 2px;
  height: 0;
  background: #dd8341;
  left: 20%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  animation: lineup 3s forwards;
}

.linedown1, .linedown2 {top: 100%; animation: linedown 3s forwards}

.content:after, .linedown2 {left: 80%; animation-delay: 1s}

@keyframes lineup {100% {top: -200px; height: 200px}}
@keyframes linedown {100% {height: 200px}}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <span class="linedown1"></span>
  <span class="linedown2"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: I would write the gradient like this: https://jsfiddle.net/mctsua7d/4/ easier than using percentage, it's also easier to adjust

Comment: Indeed, but I'll leave it to the OP to decide. :)

Comment: Nice, thanks. But I should have 2 lines growing up, and 2 lines growing down. How can I create such multiple lines using your approach? Please consider that they should appear sequentially with some delay between each other.

Comment: @ScalaBoy Glad to help. Then I would suggest adding two elements and use pseudo-elements on them (to have a total of 4) or leave them as they are now, on the .content. Which one do you prefer?

Comment: I do not understand how to control the distance between lines. I want that the left lines are shifted 20% left, and the right lines are shifter 80% left.

Comment: @ScalaBoy Tell me if we are getting close, one way of doing it.

Comment: @ScalaBoy Adjust the delays how you want them for each.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an idea with only background and gradient:

```css
.content {
  position: fixed;
  width:100%;
  height:100vh;
  background-image:
    linear-gradient(#dd8341,#dd8341),
    linear-gradient(#dd8341,#dd8341),
    linear-gradient(#dd8341,#dd8341);
  background-position:center, 10% center,calc(10% + 4px) center;
  background-size:100% 40%,2px 0,2px 0;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  animation:lineup 2s forwards linear;
}

@keyframes lineup {
 to {
    background-size:100% 40%,2px 100%,2px 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="content"></div>
```

**UPDATE**

To add delay simple add more states to the animation:

```css
.content {
  position: fixed;
  width:100%;
  height:100vh;
  background-image:
    linear-gradient(#dd8341,#dd8341),
    linear-gradient(#dd8341,#dd8341),
    linear-gradient(#dd8341,#dd8341);
  background-position:center, 20% center,80% center;
  background-size:100% 40%,2px 0,2px 0;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  animation:lineup 2s forwards linear;
}

@keyframes lineup {
 50% {
    background-size:100% 40%,2px 100%,2px 0%;
  }
  to {
    background-size:100% 40%,2px 100%,2px 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="content"></div>
```

Comment: Than you. Cool. As I wrote in my question. I should have 2 lines growing up, and 2 lines growing down. How can I create such multiple lines using this approach?

Comment: @ScalaBoy As you can see, each line is a gradient ...it's actually 2 lines, no?

Comment: Ok, but how can I control the distance between them? I want that the left lines are shifted 20% left, and the right lines are shifter 80% left. How can I control it?

Comment: @ScalaBoy it's the background-position .. adjust the 10% and the calc(10% + 4px) .. change these values

Comment: And how to introduce a delay between them?

Comment: @ScalaBoy here is https://jsfiddle.net/3szcp5mb/4/ simply change the background position in different states

Comment: Oops, talking it back then, not bad. :) Now I'm gonna lose the checkmark lol, most likely... Though it's a bit harder and time consuming to define the delays for each, calcs to get to [s] which are not even there if you only want to check them, but yea overall an advanced solution not for an average user, so plus 1 from my side. Need to get that "sportsmanship" badge going lol.